Where to look for apartment for 6-month stay in Dubai?
I am expected to travel from USA to Dubai for 6 months later this year and would need an apartment for that time period. I found some options on AirBnB but wanted to check for other options/recommendations.
Exact location of the apartment does not matter as long as the area is safe. My max budget for the rent and utilities is $1500 USD/month.
Update: this is purely personal travel, not paid by an employer.
Besides AirBnB, what other options are there?

We have another site for living and working abroad, called [expatriates.se].

"A safe area" is subjective. No area is 100% safe, they have a level of risk. A seasoned person may consider the risk to be manageable, an inexperienced one may not. I suggest you look for apartments at your level of budget, and then research the area they are in.

An internet search will give you a lot more options besides AirBnB

@Freeman, as to "I am expected to travel" by your employer? Would it not be up to your employer to provide accommodations? Exactly and I am here asking for advice from anyone who may have experience because this is personal travel. I added an update to  the question.

I’m voting to close this question because the OP appears to have done the minimum of perfunctory research before posting their question.
